# Multithreading in Reactor 2.0 - why can't I spin signals out to multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, reactive-programming, reactor

I'm running into problems with the reactor 2.0 release. Namely I am trying to set up a reactive signal flow, that fans out a signal into a pool of waiting threads. I'm very familiar with Rx and with Reactive Cocoa, but there is something basic I am missing here.

I have a basic transformation that is as follows:

```
 WorkQueueDispatcher dispatcher = new WorkQueueDispatcher("dispatch", 10, 64, {... Exception handle code here ...}


return objectStream
            .partition(partitions)
            .dispatchOn(dispatcher)
            .merge()
            .map(new Function<Object, Object>() {
                @Override
                public Object apply(Object o) {
                    try {
                        return extension.eval(o, null);
                    } catch (UnableToEvaluateException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return null;
                    }

                }
            });
```

I've tried this flow about seven or eight different ways, including different dispatchers, etc. I've tried breaking it down into a grouped event stream, and handling each element separately, then writing to a separate stream for processing. In every situation, I either see every request processing on the same thread (which works, not multi-threaded) or I get the error message that I have come to dread:

```
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Dispatcher provided doesn't support event     ordering.  For concurrent signal dispatching, refer to #partition()/groupBy()     method and assign individual single dispatchers. 
at reactor.core.support.Assert.state(Assert.java:387)
at reactor.rx.Stream.dispatchOn(Stream.java:720)
at reactor.rx.Stream.dispatchOn(Stream.java:650)
```

I've tried the following:

1. manually doing a partition/group by.
2. explicitly setting a seperate single threaded dispatcher (ring) for the earlier steps.
3. Just saying eff it, not being functional, and simply dumping to my own queue for processing.

What am I missing here? Should I not be using broadcaster to start the message loop? I really don't care at all about in order execution here.

(edited)

Here is what I am doing with my homegrown code for scale out:

```
objectStream
        .consume(new Consumer<Object>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(Object o) {
                final Object target = o;
                tpe.execute(new Runnable(){
                    /**
                     * When an object implementing interface <code>Runnable</code> is used
                     * to create a thread, starting the thread causes the object's
                     * <code>run</code> method to be called in that separately executing
                     * thread.
                     * <p/>
                     * The general contract of the method <code>run</code> is that it may
                     * take any action whatsoever.
                     *
                     * @see Thread#run()
                     */
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            //System.out.println("On thread "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
                            Timer.Context onNext = onNextTimer.time();
                            Timer.Context timer = callComponentTimer.time();
                            Object translated = extension.eval(target, null);
                            timer.close();
                            broadcaster.onNext(translated);
                            onNext.close();
                        } catch (UnableToEvaluateException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

**edit**

Okay, I updated it as follows:

```
 MetricRegistry reg = DMPContext.getContext().getMetricRegistry();


    de.init(null);


    ConsoleReporter reporter = ConsoleReporter.forRegistry(DMPContext.getContext().getMetricRegistry())
            .convertRatesTo(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .convertDurationsTo(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build();

    reporter.start(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(COUNT);

    final Function<String, Object> translator = JSON.from(Request.class);
    String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/svn/DMPidea/Request.json")));

    Broadcaster<String> stringBroadcaster = Broadcaster.create();

    final Exec exec = new Exec();


    stringBroadcaster
            .partition(10)
            .consume(new Consumer<GroupedStream<Integer, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(GroupedStream<Integer, String> groupedStream) {

                    groupedStream.dispatchOn(Environment.cachedDispatcher()).map(translator).map(new Function<Object, Object>() {
                        @Override
                        public Object apply(Object o) {
                            try {
                                System.out.println("Got thread " +Thread.currentThread().getName());
                                return de.eval(o, null);
                            } catch (UnableToEvaluateException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                return null;
                            }
                        }
                    }).consume(new Consumer<Object>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(Object o) {
                            latch.countDown();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

    for (int i=0; i<COUNT; i++)
    {

        stringBroadcaster.onNext(content);

    }
    latch.await();
```

I am still seeing single threaded execution:

Got thread dispatcherGroup-1
Got thread dispatcherGroup-1
Got thread dispatcherGroup-1
Got thread dispatcherGroup-1
Got thread dispatcherGroup-1
Got thread dispatcherGroup-1
Got thread dispatcherGroup-1

Answer (score 1):

The pattern in Reactor2.0 is to use separate `CachedDispatcher`s (`RingBufferDispatcher`s) instead of using the `WorkQueueDispatcher` or `ThreadPoolExecutorDispatcher`.  This offers splitting a stream into different threads.  This works for just parallelizing small (usually non-blocking) operations into logical streams.

**For full non-blocking execution in a separate thread pool, see my edit at the bottom.**

You will want to use Stream.groupBy() or Stream.partition() to split the stream into multiple streams, each able to be dispatched on separate threads.

1. Stream.groupBy() - buckets into streams based on the key you return
2. Stream.partition([int]) - buckets into streams based on the hashCode of streaming objects (signals), and optionally into the number of buckets you specify

After you have partitioned/grouped the stream into separate streams, you can use `flatMap()` to tell your new streams to dispatch onto separate threads.

`.flatMap(stream -> stream.dispatchOn(Environment.cachedDispatcher())`

Calling `Environment.cachedDispatcher()` is actually getting a `CachedDispatcher` (RingBufferDispatcher) from a pool of them.  The pool, by default, has a size equivalent to the number of processors for you computer.  The `CachedDispatcher`s are lazily created, so this is not ideal to do inside your call to `.dispatchOn(Dispatcher)`.

To create a pool (`DispatcherSupplier`) of `CachedDispatchers` beforehand, you can use `Environment.newCachedDispatchers(int, [groupName])`.  Here is an example from the ProjectReactor docs as to how to combine all this:

```
    DispatcherSupplier supplier1 = Environment.newCachedDispatchers(2, "groupByPool");
    DispatcherSupplier supplier2 = Environment.newCachedDispatchers(5, "partitionPool");

    Streams
        .range(1, 10)
        .groupBy(n -> n % 2 == 0) 
        .flatMap(stream -> stream
                .dispatchOn(supplier1.get()) 
                .log("groupBy")
        )
        .partition(5) 
        .flatMap(stream -> stream
                .dispatchOn(supplier2.get()) 
                .log("partition")
        )
        .dispatchOn(Environment.sharedDispatcher()) 
        .log("join")
        .consume();
```

[Reactor Docs: Partitioning Streams into separate threads](http://projectreactor.io/docs/reference/#streams-partition)

Notice in this example they have also called `.dispatchOn(Environment.sharedDispatcher())` after the last `flatMap()` call.  This is to simply join the stream back into a single `Dispatcher` thread.  In this case the `Environment.sharedDispatcher()`, which is another `RingBufferDispatcher`.

I use this strategy to partition my stream into separate threads to make blocking calls in parallel on separate `CachedDispatcher`s, then rejoin them back into a single thread on the main `Environment.sharedDispatcher()`, all in a non-blocking/reactive way, like so:

```
    // Spring's RestTemplate for making simple REST (HTTP) calls
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    List<String> urls = Arrays.asList("http://www.google.com", "http://www.imgur.com");
    Streams
        .from(urls)
        .groupBy(s -> s) // unique group (stream) per URL
        .flatMap(stream -> 
            // dispatch on separate threads per stream
            stream.dispatchOn(Environment.cachedDispatcher())
                 // blocking call in separate dispatching thread
                 .map(s -> restTemplate.getForObject(s, String.class)))
        // rejoin into single dispatcher thread
        .dispatchOn(Environment.sharedDispatcher())
        .consume(
             s -> { // consumer
                 System.out.println("---complete in stream---");
             },
             t -> { // error consumer
                 System.out.println("---exception---");
                 System.out.println(t);
             },
             s -> { // complete consumer
                 latch.countDown();
                 System.out.println("---complete---");
             });
```

**EDIT:**
For doing blocking operations in parallel you may still want to use a thread pool.  In Reactor 2.0 you can do this using a dispatcher backed by a thread pool, preferably an `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` because it will reuse threads an limit the amount of GC pressure.

The easiest way I found to do this was to use an `EventBus` using a `ThreadPoolExecutorDispatcher` backed by an `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` (which is really just a `ThreadPoolExecutor` with a few specific settings if you look at the function to create the newCachedThreadPool):

```
    // dispatcher backed by cached thread pool for limited GC pressure
    Dispatcher dispatcher = new ThreadPoolExecutorDispatcher(1024, 1024, Executors.newCachedThreadPool());

    int n = 1000000;
    EventBus bus = EventBus.create(dispatcher);
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(n);
    bus.on($("topic"), (Event<Integer> ev) -> {
        blockingServiceCall(100); // block for 100ms
        latch.countDown();
        if (ev.getData() % 1000 == 0) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + " " + Thread.activeCount());
        }
    });

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        bus.notify("topic", Event.wrap(i));
    }
    latch.await();
    System.out.println("ops/sec: " + (n * 1.0) / ((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) / 1000.0) );
```

You will need to dispatch back into a Stream after the blocking call has completed inside the consumer if you want to go back to using Streams.  As far as I know you can't simply merge them back into a stream automatically, nor can you use the ThreadPoolExecutorDispatcher backed by a cached thread pool directly by doing `Stream.dispatchOn(threadPoolExecutorDispatcher)`.

Answer (score 0):

Just scanning through, will come with a proper answer asap.
But at first isn't the problem linked to the fact you do merge() and then do your logic ? Reactive Stream is single threaded onXXX call per spec (in RxJava too and Akka Stream too).

Like in Rx I would just carry the processing work inside the flatmapped stream or just consume if you don't need to merge back (which is a contention point if you think about it).

```
return objectStream
        .partition(partitions)
        .consume( partitionStream ->
           partitionStream
             .dispatchOn(Environment.cachedDispatcher()) 
             .consume( o -> {
                try {
                    return extension.eval(o, null);
                } catch (UnableToEvaluateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }

            }
        ));
```

Comment: WorkQueueDispatcher is not directly supported in Rx, however cachedDispatcher returns a pooled dispatcher (default to ringBuffer) out of N (default number of processor), so in my past example I will assign N partition with N different dispatchers, effectively scaling up.

Also note that 2.0 and onwards have a specific not standard component that is going to superseed WorkQueueDispatcher overtime, RingBufferWorkProcessor which is truely a Reactive Streams component that scale up as many subscriber as you want.

Comment: Pred, okay, so the dispatchOn will select a independant thread out of a pool with 2.0? When I printed the thread name, it was always coming up the main thread, not a seperate thread. I am using the generic Static Enviornment setup. Could that be the problem?

Comment: So, I tested this version of it, and strangely, I am still seeing single threaded behavior at this point. I see the thread saying that it's coming off of a dispatcherGroup, but the threadId is always dispatcherGroup-1, and I don't see any other threads currently created.

Answer (score 0):

I've done both with the merge, and without. Didn't make any difference. The code base here is 2.0. I'm fine with it being single threaded once I hit the dispatchOn, but I need to take advantage of multi-core (which is, after all, a big reason for leveraging FRP). My benchmarks didn't reveal any threading occurring, and printing the name of the thread didn't show any fan out to independent threads.

Note that I am using Java 7 here instead of 8 (and man, would I kill for lamda functions and their syntax here).